# Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is : Consider an array of numeric strings where each string is a positive number with anywhere from 1 to 10^6 digits. Sort the array's elements in non-decreasing, or ascending order of their integer values and return the sorted array.

```
vector<string> bigSorting(vector<string> unsorted) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<unsorted.size() ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<unsorted.size()-1; j++){
            long int a = stol(unsorted[j]);
            long int b = stol(unsorted[j+1]);
            if(a > b){
                string x = unsorted[j];
                unsorted[j] = unsorted[j+1];
                unsorted[j+1] = x;
            }
        }
    }
    return unsorted;
}
```

I made the above function for the question and it gave an error :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  stol
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 450]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

What is the meaning of this error code and how do I fix it?

Comment: 1 to 10^6 digits, stol throws std::out_of_range. How many digits does `long` support? 20-ish on 64-bit. You cannot use stol for this.

Comment: @dratenik isn't 10^6 lesser than a 20 digit number?

Comment: as far as I know 10^6 digits > 20 digits

Comment: Moreover, your sorting with complexity O(n^2) will likely fail for large problem sizes (=n)

Comment: You can simply use `unsorted[i] < unsorted[j]`, which uses lexicographical comparison, provided, your strings are consistent (i.e. no intermixing 0042 and 42 for the same number)

Comment: To clarify: 10 to the 6th is 1,000,000, which, at 7 digits, will fit in a `long`, but the input is up to 1,000,000 **digits** in length, not up to the number 1,000,000.

Comment: Pure string comparison will do 1234 < 234 < 88 < 9 which may not be what you want. The task appears to ask you to implement numeric-like comparison on strings.

Comment: Why not simply use `std::sort` with the appropriate lambda function?  That bubble sort you wrote should have been the last resort, and would probably fail anyway due to timeout issues with a large size.

Comment: @Walter can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That was my first approach but I couldn't think of an appropriate lambda function.

Comment: @SamitKapoor `return stol(string1) < stol(string2);`.  And if you had no idea of `std::sort`, [this link shows various sorting algorithm implementation, written in modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).  If this question is from one of those online competition websites, don't go armed with a naive bubble-sort if you are asked to sort the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie doesn't work shows same error code.

Comment: We have no idea what changes you actually made.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie we do know the input has numbers up to 1 million digits in length, so any lambda involving stol is doomed to fail

Comment: @SamitKapoor you have two strings with numbers in them, how would you compare them? If their length differs, decide immediately based on that, otherwise go digit by digit until you find a difference.

Comment: Yes, I see that the lambda needs to consist of two steps -- string size, and then digit comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your error originates form your attempt to read a number with many digits (up to a million) into a 64bit number, which can hold all numbers up to `1<<64=18446744073709551616`, i.e. no numbers with more than 20 digits.

Hence you must find another way to compare those strings. The question is not very clear about leading zeros, but let us assume that the numbers are represented without leading zeros. Then the `std::string`s, representing the numbers, can be compared by their `size()` and, if that is equal, lexicographically, which is implemented by `operator<` between `std::string`s, i.e.

```
std::vector<std::string> bigSorting(std::vector<std::string> unsorted)
{
    std::sort(unsorted.begin(), unsorted.end(), 
        [](std::string const&x, std::string const&y) {
            return x.size()==y.size()? x<y : x.size() < y.size();
        });
    return unsorted;
}
```

If there are leading zeros, you must adapt your method accordingly.